# format to select academic year format 'yyyy'-'yy' (Example: 2015-16)

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, bootstrap-datepicker

I dint find to any option to show academic/finance year as 'yyyy'-'yy' format.
example: 2015-16.
I am using angular.js and  bootstrap date-picker plugin.

Please help

Comment: Bootstrap date picker means why you have added the tag as angularjs? Your question is not clear. Give some example which you tried.

Comment: It might be easier to display two dates, the first one in `yyyy` format, and the second one constructed from the first one + 1 year in `yy` format